# Ruby on Rails: Creating a Calendar, get the next week (redirect loop)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I'm creating a Calendar to view of a week without the Calendar gem.  (It will get pretty specific past the use of that gem).

When I render a view to see a page (index) it will display the dates and days for that particular week.  How can I make a button that is clickable that will change those dates to the previous week or the next week?

I'm confused on how to do it, and am looking for coding suggestions of course.  How I have attempted this so far is I have created two helper functions to add the days to my current variables.  Then I want to display the same page after the helper function updates to the next week or previous week.
Here is how I am calling my helper function 
`<%= link_to '<', week_ahead, class: 'month-arrow' %>`

```
def week_ahead
    @viewDate = @viewDate + 7.days
    @weekStart = @viewDate.beginning_of_week(start_day = :monday)
  end
  helper_method :week_ahead

  def week_back
    @viewDate = @viewDate - 7.days
    @weekStart = @viewDate.beginning_of_week(start_day = :monday)
  end
  helper_method :week_back
```

Here is what I am using in my controller

```
  def index
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @viewDate = Date.today
    @weekStart = @viewDate.beginning_of_week(start_day = :monday)
  end
```

If I put a `redirect_to user_path`  command in the helper function it gives a redirect loop.  I still want my view to update to the next week when they click on the "next arrow".

Answer (score 1):

Use simple calender gem. It is really helperful.https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar